# GRPC: How to set/modify a field after it has already been built

Tags: kotlin, grpc

Say I return from a function called `external()` something like

```
return hotelRoomReservation.newBuilder()
    .setCheckInTime(user.checkInTime)
    .setCheckOutTime(user.checkOutTime)
    .build()
```

and set it to a variable called `reservation`. Then, at a later time, say in the calling function, I want to edit one of the fields. What I would like to do is:

```
reservation.updateCheckInTime(newCheckInTime)
```

How can I achieve this after the GRPC message has already been built?

Answer (score 1):

You will have to convert the message back to a builder (`toBuilder()`), add the update, build it again, and overwrite the variable holding the message.  This isn't really different from e.g. a `String`, where you can't modify a character in the string, but you could convert to a `StringBuilder`, make some changes, and build it into a string again.

(This is assuming you're not using the Kotlin proto bindings, in which case you can use `.copy` and don't need a builder, though you still need to change the variable.)

Comment: I'm completely new to Kotlin. What do you mean by the Kotlin proto bindings?

Comment: gRPC uses protocol buffers to represent its messages with the builders.  Protocol buffers have [special extra support for Kotlin](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/kotlintutorial) that you can opt into.